# Algorithm for all combinations of arrays of a set of elements

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I want an algorithm that works like this:

Given a number of elements:

```
A B C D E F
```

The algorithm should produce all combinations of arrays containing those elements:

```
[A,B,C,D,E,F]
[AB,C,D,E,F]
[ABC,D,E,F]
[A,BC,D,E,F]
[A,B,C,DEF]
[ABCDEF]
```

Invalid combinations are (for example):

```
[AC,B,D,E,F]
[AB,BC,D,E,F]
[BC,DE,FA]
```

That is, the elements should stay in order.

**EDIT:**
I want to use the algorithm on english sentences to detect compound nouns.

For example:

```
On the table is a water jug.
```

Should be recognised as a sequence of following word classes.

```
Pronoun, Determiner, Noun, Verb, Determiner, Noun
```

but not

```
Pronoun, Determiner, Noun, Verb, Determiner, Noun, Noun
```

Comment: These are not called combinations, probably partitions or groupings.

Comment: ...what have you tried? This sounds a typical homework problem...

Comment: Please describe what you have tried, and where specifically you are stuck.

Comment: @izomorphius They could be seen as combinations of range lengths, eg. the first can be represented by `1,1,1,1,1,1`, the second `2,1,1,1,1,0` ... The pool of valid values for a range length is `0-6`

Comment: @Asad: and only the last element can be zero.. that's a far stretched (and bad) analogy, let's not call them combinations, shall we?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath No, multiple elements can be zero. For example, the last one is `6,0,0,0,0,0`. The only additional restriction is that you have to filter the set of combinations for those that add up to 6.

Comment: @Asad: sorry.. I meant only the last elemnt*s* can be zero. Eg: 2,1,1,1,1,0 and 2,1,1,1,0,1 is the same thing. And *please* don't call the combinations.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Haha alright, I'm no mathematician, but I know from experience how touchy the math first years are about terminology

Comment: I edited the post. Should be clear now.

Comment: you have a 2^(n-1) state for check.but if you have a correct english sentences so you can use a bound for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the problem to this one:

For `n` letters you have `n-1` places between them.
You need to choose whether to place a separator at each of the `n-1` positions.

The pseudocode will be something like this:

```
choose(set, size)
    if (size <= 0) return
    set1 = set
    set2 = set
    choose(set1+1, size-1);
    choose(set2+1, size-1);
    set1 = ',' U set1+1  //set1+1 here denotes the subset starting at second position
    set2 = ' ' U set2+1
    add set1, set2 to the output group
```

And invoke by `choose(A, n-1)`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem can be solved using recursion. Take A,B,C,D,E,F as an example. We can combine A and B to form an new element AB, the remaining elements C,D,E,F can be regards as the same problem and solved recursively. Also we can combine A,B,C to form an new elements ABC and the remaining elements is D,E,F. The code is below:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>


using namespace std;

void sequential_combination(char input[],int start, int length,vector<string>& result)
{
     if(start>=length)
     {
        cout<<"[";
        for(int i=0;i<result.size()-1;++i)cout<<result[i]<<",";
        cout<<result[result.size()-1];
        cout<<"]";
        cout<<endl;
     }
     else
     {
         string prefix="";
         for(int i=start;i<length;++i)
         {
                 prefix+=input[i];
                 result.push_back(prefix);
                 sequential_combination(input,i+1,length,result);
                 result.pop_back();
         }
     }     
}

int main()
{

    char input[6]={'A','B','C','D','E','F'};
    vector<string> result;
    sequential_combination(input,0,6,result);
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Hope it helps!